# How do I split a string into an array, but keep multiple digit numbers/words together?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm making a simple LISP interpreter in Java and I have been having trouble figuring out how to properly split the user's input so that each character is on separate indexes except for multiple digit numbers and potentially words. I also need to get rid of white space which kind of brings up some other problems as well.

Right now the line that I'm using to split the user's input into a string in order to compute is:

```
String[] mainFunc = equation.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("(?!^)");

Input: (+ 4 3)
Output: 
0) (
1) +
2) 4
3) 3
4) )
```

This worked for what I need up until 2 or more digits because it would split them into separate indexes. Then I tried another regex that I found on here that almost took care of what I needed, which is:

```
String[] mainFunc = equation.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

Input: (- 10 3)
Output:
0) (- 
1) 10
2)  
3) 3
4) )
```

This almost worked out for me but then I need to split that first parenthesis and operator, as well as getting rid of that white space (I tried trimming in a loop and I wasn't able to get rid of that space in index 2 for some reason).

Any ideas on the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The split expression consumes, so you can eat the whitespace there. Split on whitespace or before/after non-digit/non-whitespace:

```
String[] mainFunc = equation.split("\\s+|(?<=[^ \\d])\\s*|\\s*(?=[()-])");
```

This works for your example.

---

```
String equation = "(- 10 3)";
String[] mainFunc = equation.split("\\s+|(?<=[^ \\d])\\s*|\\s*(?=[^ \\d])");
Arrays.stream(mainFunc).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
(
-
10
3
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @reekah I've modified the regex to be more general, eg handling the other operators etc

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and mentioned output, I would do as follows

- all inside elements can be split with space(**\\s+**)
- Since for first and last parenthesis there is no splitting term. So you will have to separate from inside terms like below

> (- 10 3)    to ( - 10 3 )

- Now all elements can be simply split by space

Here is my code

```
    String equation="(- 10 3)";
    equation=equation.replaceAll("\\(","\\( ");
    equation=equation.replaceAll("\\)"," \\)");
    String[] mainFunc = equation.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainFunc));
```

And Output is

```
[(, -, 10, 3, )]
```

Answer (score 0):

oh..finally I got simple answer..

```
String[] arr = a.split("(?=\\D)(?)");
```

instead of D,  W also works.. when there's also words.

But, need to trim.